# How to count number of True and False blocks in a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
                                    col
2023-05-04 10:34:51.002100665      True
2023-05-04 10:34:51.007100513      True
2023-05-04 10:34:51.012100235      True
2023-05-04 10:34:51.017100083     False
2023-05-04 10:34:51.022099789     False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.610740595     False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.615740466      True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.620740227      True
2023-05-04 10:35:23.625740082     False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.630739797      True
```

How do I count the number of True and False blocks present in it? The result should be:

```
Number of True blocks:  3
Number of False blocks: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 'col' your column, you can remove the identical successive values with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = df.loc[df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()), 'col'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
col  
True     3
False    2
dtype: int64
```

Intermediates:

* only those rows will be considered

```
                                 col  shift  ≠ shift
2023-05-04 10:34:51.002100665   True    NaN     True  *
2023-05-04 10:34:51.007100513   True   True    False
2023-05-04 10:34:51.012100235   True   True    False
2023-05-04 10:34:51.017100083  False   True     True  *
2023-05-04 10:34:51.022099789  False  False    False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.610740595  False  False    False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.615740466   True  False     True  *
2023-05-04 10:35:23.620740227   True   True    False
2023-05-04 10:35:23.625740082  False   True     True  *
2023-05-04 10:35:23.630739797   True  False     True  *
```

Comment: This does not work for me...

Comment: @Mike can you be more specific? Also please provide a fully reproducible input (output of `df.to_dict('list')`) as [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76570857/edit) (comments are not good for pasting data/code).

Comment: Nvm, my bad. Had a bug on my side. Thank for your rapid response! :)